# how do i sort words into a structure array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, structure

I am very new to C++ so go easy on the words that I may or may not understand... 
we are given a paragraph in string form and we are supposed to grab each word from the string and populate an array, and display the array. We learned about structures today so thats why we are supposed to output the docWordCount(and also why something is probably wrong with it....)

What I am trying to do is to move along the string until I find a space, and when I do I use the .substr command to copy the word into the array. I originally tried to use static_cast to find if there was a space or not, I Am not sure if the problem was that it doesnt work like that, or I did something wrong(probably latter). Everytime I would move along the string, I would increase the word count by 1, so it would output all of the word instead of whats infront of it. Also I should mention that when I compile the code, it outputs the text and then it gives me a "Debug assertion failed! [...] expression: string subscript out of range." error in another window.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    struct wordCount
    {
        string word;
        int count;
    };

    wordCount docWordCount [500];   
    for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
        docWordCount[i].word = "";
        docWordCount[i].count = 0;
    }

string text ="If there's one good thing that's come out of the European debt crisis\
        it's that the U.S. has been able to shield itself from much of \
            the mess. The sentiment will continue in 2012 as the U.S.  \
            economy is expected to grow faster than its European counterparts. \
        That's according to the Organization for Economic Cooperation and \
        Development which says the U.S. economy will expand at a 2.9% \
            annual rate in the first quarter and then a 2.8% rate in the second quarter.";
cout << text << endl;

int wordLength = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
    if (text[i] == ' ' ) //if there isnt a space
        wordLength++;

    if (text[i] == !' ' ) //if there is a space
        docWordCount[i].word = text.substr(i - wordLength, i);
    }

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
cout << docWordCount[i].word << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

What it should look like is

```
If
Theres
one
good
thing
```

etc... is what I am trying to do sound? Is there an easier way to solve this?

Comment: Is there a coding error?  I am not familiar with a logical negation of a space character.  The code is: `if (text[i] == !' ' )`

Comment: Can you use library features? Never reinvent the wheel: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f53e32151af5465 or replace all `set` with `vector`

Comment: i was trying to say if text[i] is a space. i have no idea if that actually works or not. i originally tried using static_cast, but i wasnt sure if that worked or not, so i tried something different

Comment: for sehe: we haven't learned the lines 24 onward in your link, which i assume is the sorting into alphabetical bit. also, what does istream_iterator do exactly?

Comment: The `!` operator converts non-zero to `0`, and zero to `1`.

Comment: @user3470528 Vlad has been nice enough to post improved code.  I am confident Vlad's improvements will help resolve the problems.

Answer (score 0):

A few errors, but otherwise sound.

1. You confuse the index to the `text` with the index into the word array; create a new variable `wordIndex` for the latter.
2. The operators for checking a space or not are wrong. `==` means *is*, use `!=` for *is not*.
3. You should iterate `i` for `text.length()`
4. Better to change the `500` hard code to a constant.
5. Critically, you want `text.substr(i - wordLength, wordLength)`; i.e. the second parameter is the length, not the end index of the substring.

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains several bugs. For example this statement

```
if (text[i] == !' ' ) //if there is a space
```

is invalid. It compares character `text[i]` with boolean value false ( `!' '` )

Try the following code (without testing). Maybe it contains less bugs than your code.:)

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    struct wordCount
    {
        std::string word;
        int count;
    };

    const size_t N = 500;
    wordCount docWordCount[N] = {};   

    std::string text ="If there's one good thing that's come out of the European debt crisis\
                       it's that the U.S. has been able to shield itself from much of \
                       the mess. The sentiment will continue in 2012 as the U.S.  \
                       economy is expected to grow faster than its European counterparts. \
                       That's according to the Organization for Economic Cooperation and \
                       Development which says the U.S. economy will expand at a 2.9% \
                       annual rate in the first quarter and then a 2.8% rate in the second quarter.";

    std::cout << text << std::endl;

    size_t n = 0;
    std::string::size_type i = 0;

    while ( n < N && i < text.size() )
    {
        while ( i < text.size() && text[i] == ' ' ) ++i;

        std::string::size_type j = i;
        while ( i < text.size() && text[i] != ' ' ) ++i;

        if ( j != i ) docWordCount[n++].word.assign( text, j, i - j );
    }


    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) std::cout << docWordCount[i].word << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It would be simpler if you would use member function of class std::string as for example `find`

By the way the name of the thread does not correspond to its description. There was said nothing about sort.